# C# - Does TcpClient connection (& listening) use bandwith?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I wrote a small c# winform app that connects to my DSC alarm (via Envisalink4 by Eyez-On) and listens for TCP data sent by the alarm.
Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipAddress, port);

Thread tcpThread = new Thread(o =>
{
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];

    while (started)
    {
        int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(data, 0, 4096);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string dataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseData);
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
});
tcpThread.Start();
```

My question is - Other than when the alarm sends data, is any bandwidth being used while this code is waiting/listening for the server? Is there any "TCP connection overhead" while listening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using Synchronous read() method which blocks while waiting for data and uses very little bandwidth.

Comment: So the tcp connection does use additional bandwidth - even if no data is being sent/received?

Comment: The checking for incoming messages is done in a windows timer and uses a very little amount of bandwidth.  When data is received the application is then notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sniffer like Wireshark to check your tcp connection

Comment: I tried using Fiddler (didn't show anything) - is Wireshark better? I also looked on my compuer's network traffic on my router, but there was too much "noise" for me to decern my app from normal "windows-sending-my-life-to-microsoft-servers" traffic =/

Comment: Wireshark is quite simple to use and you can filter for ip and tcp in your example